# OpenPyxl Pie chart set width of categories

Tags: python, charts, pie-chart, openpyxl

I create a pie chart with 56 pieces.

```
piechart = PieChart()
piechart.title = table_name
piechart.add_data(values)
piechart.style = 26
piechart.width = 28
piechart.set_categories(leg)
ws.add_chart(piechart, 'D35')
```

At categories list I see only 6 first categories because chart area is small. Can openpyxl show the categories at 2,3 columns or more? How can I change width of categories area?

Comment: I suspect you'll have to do some reverse engineering of an existing Excel file for this.

Comment: You mean edit an existing chart by hand?

Comment: No, create one in Excel and look at the source code.